# How to turn off the Location Services dialogue in iOS?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I need to disable the Location Services dialogue automatically.  Actually I am using the Location Services for Flurry in my app but I need to disable the dialogue programmatically by which it will not ask the user for location service.

I am using this but it doesn't help me to solve my problem.

```
 [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Is there any way to disable the dialogue box programmatically?

Comment: If you mean the permissions dialogue for location services, you cannot remove that. Once you ask for this service the user always has to accept. Anything else and your app will not get approved.

Comment: means there is no way to stop the alert dialogue else remove the location services?

Comment: @freshking ok is this any way to set the value to don't allow programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I found a solution to stop the location dialogue by commenting this line,

```
 //    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and it solved my problem. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. If your app using the location service definitely it will ask the user's permission. You dont have any control over that

Comment: ok is this any way to set the value to don't allow programmatically?

Comment: Simply don't start updating location. Check the Flurry SDK Documentation.

Comment: @Steve there is no way. Why you need disabled location services in your app? Just do not use them at all.